# Regular Expression to extract alphanumeric parts of a URL?

Tags: regex

Given any URL, like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/v1/summary/1243PQ/details/P1/9981
```

How do I extract the numeric or alphanumeric part of the URL? I.e. the following strings from the url given above:

```
1. v1
2. 1243PQ
3. P1
4. 9981
```

To rephrase, a regex to extract strings from a string (URL) which have at least 1 digit and 0 or more alphabet characters, separated by `'/'`.

I tried to capture a repeating group `(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+` and `([a-zA-Z]{0,100}[0-9]{1,100})+` but it didn't work. In hindsight intuition does say this shouldn't work. I am unsure how do I match patterns over a group and not just a single character.

Comment: I've added the attempt. I went through https://regexone.com/ and few stack overflow questions, before putting this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
(\d*\w+\d+\w*)
```

**EDIT**: actually, this should be sufficient

```
(\w+\d+\w*)
```

or

```
(\w*\d+\w*)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But why did you put `\w+`? It seems to work with `(\d*\w*\d+\w*)` as well.

Comment: No specific reason, in this case it should indeed yield the same results. The difference between + and * is 'zero or one' vs 'zero or more'. Here we are dealing with at most one 'word character' plus a digit, so both + and * would activate.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you really want:

> Extracting parts with only numbers or with numbers following alphabets

then; I can suggest this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-z]*\b
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kb371o/1)

I use `\b` to assert position of a word boundary or a part.
As numbers are required and alphabets can comes before or after that I use above regex.

If following alphabets are not required then I can suggest this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*\b
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kb371o/2)

Comment: uhh... so that's what word boundaries could be used for. I didn't get it 'till now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `\/[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Explanation:

`\/` - match `/` literally

`[a-zA-Z]*` - 0+ letters

`\d+` - 1+ digits - thanks to this, we require at least one digits

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ letters or digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QehPw1/2)

It will captrure together with `/` at the beginning, so you need to trim it.

Comment: It will fail with `/1a2b` It will capture only `/1a`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this:

```
(\w*\d+\w*) with the g (global) regex option
```

On the example URL, it would look like this:

```js
const regex = /(\w*\d+\w*)/g;
const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/v1/summary/1243PQ/details/P1/9981';

console.log(url.match(regex))
```